# R/knitr: How to cancel knitting without creting a document at all?

Tags: r, knitr

There is [`knit_exit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.30/topics/knit_exit), but is there a way to exit knitting and not to write a document at all? The already processed part of the Rmd file should be just ignored.

I have implemented all the analysis and formatting into the Rmd files and I prefer not to separate the analysis into different file from the Rmd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking the file created by `knitr::knit()` and deleting it with R `unlink()` in case the file did not meet certain criteria (errors, too short). In this case there were data-related conditions for creating the file and those could be known only while deep inside the `.Rmd` file.